# VBA will recognize a table name using a variable for the name when it has a ", " and sometimes only when it has "__"

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that will insert a row at the bottom of a table and fill the table in. The macro uses a name selected from a commandbox in a userform. The names are written like this "Last name, First name". The tables in excel are named "Transfer_Data_Lastname__Firstname". Excel will recognize some of the tables for some names using the ", " between names, and some names it won't recognize it unless I use the "__" like it is in the table name.

I don't understand why it works for some and not others. I have found though that if it works one way it will not work the other way as well.

Here are some examples of it working and not working. I used this in the immediate window to try and figure out which ones work and which ones don't.

```
?TransferSheet.ListObjects("Transfer_Data_KIDD__CHRISTIAN").Range.Address =
$P$9:$Z$10

?TransferSheet.ListObjects("Transfer_Data_KIDD, CHRISTIAN").Range.Address = runtime error 9

?TransferSheet.ListObjects("Transfer_Data_WILLIAMS, CHASE").Range.Address =
$P$19:$Z$25

?TransferSheet.ListObjects("Transfer_Data_WILLIAMS__CHASE").Range.Address = runtime error 9

?TransferSheet.ListObjects("Transfer_Data_NEBEKER__JORDAN").Range.Address =
$P$26:$Z$27

?TransferSheet.ListObjects("Transfer_Data_SEARLE, AARON").Range.Address = runtime error 9

?TransferSheet.ListObjects("Transfer_Data_PITCHER__LANCE").Range.Address = 
$P$34:$Z$35
```

Can someone help. I need it to work for me using the ", " every time because that is how the names are pulled in from the report. Also please excuse my lack of knowledge and ability to speak programmer. I have taught myself everything I know about programming and thus I don't know all the lingos.

Comment: I don't think you can have space in the name at all, try creating a table manually and name it `Transfer_Data_WILLIAMS, CHASE`, it should fail.

Answer (score 1):

Spaces are not allowed when naming list objects (tables). Sometimes--as you experienced--Excel will still figure it out but you just got lucky there. If you need **separators** in list object names then use **underscores** or **periods**.

The case of "Transfer_Data_WILLIAMS__CHASE" looks like a spelling mistake: Excel cannot find a list object thus named while the name itself is proper. Please check the actual spelling of the name.